# Controller is not loaded in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am doing an app which has a side menu when clicking on one if the side menu items the app loads the linked template to that state correctly. However the controller of that state is not loaded at all. I tried debugging and checking the console but nothing. please may I get some help in that ?!

This is the code I am running for the side menu :

```
`    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

     <ion-side-menu-content>
     <ion-nav-bar class="header" animation="nav-title-slide-ios7">
    <ion-nav-buttons >
        <img class="title" src="logo.png">
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left" id="sideMenuContent">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Navigation</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.COE">
              <img src="img/aduSampleLogo.png" class="logosample"/>
              <b>COE</b>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.COBA">
              <img src="img/aduSampleLogo.png" class="logosample"/>
              <b>COBA</b>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="CAS">
              <img src="img/aduSampleLogo.png" class="logosample"/>
              <b>CAS</b>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-side-menu>
 </ion-side-menus>
```

`

And this is my controller.js file code :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('homeController', function($scope) {

})
.controller('COEController', function($scope) {

    console.log(" COEController is loaded");

}) ;
```

Plus the app.js file :

```
angular.module('starter',['ionic','angularCircularNavigation','starter.services', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
 })

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"
})
.state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
          'menuContent' :{
              templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
              controller: "homeController"
          }
      }
})
  .state('app.COE', {
      url: '/COE',
      views: {
          'menuContent' :{
              templateUrl: "templates/COE.html",
              controller: "COEController"
          }
      }

  }) ;

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

And these are the errors I am getting :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: rippleExtensionId is not defined
  (anonymous function)  bootstrap.js:2
  (anonymous function)  bootstrap.js:2
GET http://localhost:63342/AdvisingAppV3/www/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
  (anonymous function)  ionic.bundle.js:10615
  forEach   ionic.bundle.js:7950
  forEach.append    ionic.bundle.js:10613
  JQLite.(anonymous function)   ionic.bundle.js:10735
  IonicModule.run.factory.getRenderer.enter ionic.bundle.js:39394
  updateView    ionic.bundle.js:42977
  IonicModule.directive.directive.compile.eventHook ionic.bundle.js:42933
  $get.Scope.$broadcast ionic.bundle.js:20605
  $state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition ionic.bundle.js:34122
  deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback ionic.bundle.js:19197
   (anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:19283
   $get.Scope.$eval ionic.bundle.js:20326
   $get.Scope.$digest   ionic.bundle.js:20138
   $get.Scope.$apply    ionic.bundle.js:20430
   done ionic.bundle.js:16003
   completeRequest  ionic.bundle.js:16217
   xhr.onreadystatechange   ionic.bundle.js:16156
```

Comment: Does it work on the browser?

Comment: Yes it does I discovered that using chrome developers tools, I can actually see the controller console msgs on chrome console. However webstorm kept showing errors and when I debug it crashes and never stops at the break point.